# real-time html links on github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, real-time, github-pages

Is there a way you could render links as a streaming data input w/ css/html or js?

Ex: say you have 10 github repos. and you want them all to appear on your webpage in a dropdown(as a series of links). Then user deletes one so only 9 should appear. Is there a name for this or is this possible? *assuming this is being done with github pages.

Comment: "Is there a way you could..." is almost always a lead in to a question that is outside the scope of this format.  The answer to that is probably yes, but I think you really want to ask if what you have tried is the right approach, or why what you did try didn't work.  see [ask]

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/